# Корректно ли предложение с точки зрения синтаксиса?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, спп, и

*«Простите за долгий ответ и что не привезли товары».*
Корректно ли так писать? Смущает, что тут сочинительный союз «и» соединяет второстепенные члены главного предложения и придаточное предложение. Или можно только так:

- Простите за долгий ответ и за то, что не привезли товары.
- Простите, что долго отвечали и что не привезли товары.

Если предложение корректно, то запятая перед «и» не нужна?

Comment: Не лучше ли так: "Простите, что не привезли товары и долго не отвечали".

Answer (score 1):

**Простите за поздний ответ и за то, что не привезли товары.**
**Простите, что долго не отвечали и [что] не привезли товары.**

В толковом словаре:
[**долгий**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9)

1. Продолжительный, длящийся в течение значительного времени; длительный (противоп.: короткий). *Долгий урок. Долгий путь. Долгая разлука. Долгая жизнь. Долгий взгляд* (пристальный, внимательный). *Долгие годы прошли с тех пор* (много лет). // Протяжный (о песне). *Что-то слышится родное В долгих песнях ямщика* (Пушкин).
2. Устар. =Длинный (1 зн.). *Долгая грива. Долгий нос журавля. Волос долог, да ум короток* (поговорка).

В вашем контексте предполагается, что кто-то долго не отвечал на письмо. В этом случае говорить "долгий ответ" — неверно, так как это означает продолжительный, длительный ответ.

*― Это долгий* [длинный] *ответ, Коль, ― мягко сказал он* (В. Рыбаков. Вода и кораблики).

Правильно: поздний, несвоевременный, запоздалый ответ.

[**поздний**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ag=x&bts=x&lop=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
3. Задержавшийся появлением, наступивший, совершённый после обычного или нужного времени; запоздалый. *Поздний гость. Поздняя любовь. **Поздний ответ на письмо.*** // Несвоевременный. *Поздний совет. Позднее сожаление. Поздние проклятия.*

*Надеюсь, Вы примете во внимание смягчающие мою вину обстоятельства и не обидитесь за поздний ответ* (С. Маршак); *Скажи им, что эти строки ― запоздалый ответ на Юркино поздравительное письмецо* (Ю. Даниэль).